# Stopping <task:scheduler> tasks

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

Our application runs both in client server mode and in standalone mode, when server code is embedded in the client process.
In spring beans xml I have scheduled tasks, like

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="link-to-server" method="heartbeat" fixed-rate="1000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

In the standalone mode the application is not exiting, because scheduler threads are not daemon threads. How can I stop them or make these threads daemon?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't make them daemon, that stops threads way too abrupt and therefor can leave your process in an inconsistent state. I believe a standard shutdown of the Spring context, and therefor the scheduler, simply [interrupts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) all running threads. You should therefor poll [Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) in your tasks to determine shutdown. Blocking methods like [Object.wait()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) will throw `InterruptedException` upon interruption.

Comment: Not sure that I can always know when shutdown Spring context. This code is used in many tests, and sometimes people just write main method, create context and call objects. It will be hard to change all this code now. I prefer some spring solution, in the same xml

Comment: Spring registers a JVM shutdown hook, so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: I see that it is not working. The JVM finishes only if I put System.exit()

Comment: Do you have a long running task or a task that uses infinite looping? Have you tried narrowing it down by e.g. configuring just one task that only prints something to the console?